# Spring override @PreAuthorize annotation in subclass

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-annotations

Basically I have one Controller that is permitted for regular user and I want to have the same controller to be accessible by admin in a different path. 
So I thought this would work:

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('USER')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/name", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getName() {
        return service.getCurrentUserName();
    }
}

@RestController
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class UserController extends UserController{
}
```

But I can call both /user/name and /admin/name with the USER role. So it kind of ignores the PreAuthorize annotation on the subclass.

Is there any way to re-use the UserController methods and just add a different security PreAuthorize to them without rewriting them for Admin?

Answer (score 1):

The controller methods are registered in superclass, so the superclass annotation applies.

The only way I know to have a kind of dynamic annotation, is to use a `#root` inside the `@PreAuthorize`. You could modify the parent class that way :

```
@RestController
@PreAuthorize("hasRole(#root.this.requiredRole)")
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserController {
    protected String getRequiredRole() {
        return "USER";
    }
    ...
}
```

And for the child class :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin")
public class AdminController extends UserController {
    protected String getRequiredRole() {
        return "ADMIN";
    }
    ...
}
```

That way, the methods of the parent class will correctly require ADMIN role when called for a `AdminController` object, since the string value of `@PreAuthorize` will be preprocessed by SpEL, while still requiring USER role for a true `UserController`.

Comment: By now (spring 3) you need to use #root.this.requiredRole. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I only need to add, that the method must be public and not protected currently, or a `EL1004E: Method call: Method getRequiredRole() cannot be found on type my.package.AdminController` will be launched